# Spring Boot - Detect change in AWS secret manager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

We have a spring boot application which uses AWS secret manager to store various secrets, and when the application starts we load all the secrets in map and use them to avoid cost involved in querying secret manager for each request. So any change in AWS secret manager would need redeployment/restart of the application.

So is there a way to detect the change/addition in secrets stored in secret manager, and refresh the application with new values, some sort of event driven method? Other option is to cache the secrets for certain interval and reload them after interval is completed. But I prefer first approach to reload secrets only when it is changed/added. Or is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with AWS EventBridge to trigger Lambda function to update your application:
The event pattern will be like this:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "UpdateSecret",
      "PutSecretValue"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "secretId": [
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*:*:secret:secret_name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You need to configure this event to trigger your Lambda function to restart the ECS tasks or EKS pods or whatever you want.

Comment: Our application is hosted as a jar on EC2 instances. How can we trigger event to all servers in load balanced target group?

Comment: It's another thing @Manel. The flow above is to trigger the change based on SecretManager update. And then what you need to do next is about how you deploy your applications. It should be complicated or simple depends on how much downtime you can handle. Simple flow is just cp the jar file tp all EC2s and then replace the old one. Complicated flow is yeah, much more scripts